# Google Analytics / Cordova / PhoneGap: What traffic to look for?

Tags: android, cordova, google-analytics, phonegap-plugins

I've tried to do my due diligence in searching, but I can't find anything relating specifically to this.

I have an app that uses the Google Analytics plugin from PhoneGap. I can run it on an emulator and run Wireshark to monitor the network traffic. What can I look at in Wireshark to make sure my app is reaching out to Google to make sure it gets counted when I expect it to?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: On the GA side, you can check your real-time reports to see if hits are coming in.